# React Router rendering wrong component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using a HashRouter to render different pages. The problem I am having is that when I visit
/service/app/sort, it renders `<MainPage />` when I am expecting it to render `<ChildPage />`.

Here's similar to what my router looks like

```
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/service/app">
          <MainPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/service/app/sort">
          <ChildPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
```

Additional information that may help:

on my `<MainPage />`, I have a button to redirect onClick

```
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSortClick = () => {
    console.log('click me')
    let path = "/service/app/sort";
    history.push(path);
  };
```

When I click it once, I get the 'click me' console.log and the link changes to /service/app/sort, but it's still the `<MainPage />`. If I click it one more time, I get the warning

"Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably facing this problem because the start of the URL is being interpreted as truthy by react-router-dom, and is letting you access the `/service/app` anyway.

For example, the `/service/app` route will not only detect this route, but will also detect `/service/app/1` or `/service/app1` just because it has `/service/app` in the path.

To prevent this, you need to pass the `exact` property to the route, so react-router will understand that you need to access exactly this route to render that component.

```
<Route path="/service/app" exact={true}>
  <MainPage />
</Route>
```